# flinksql create table Reported a mistake

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I used flink sql to create a flink table but got an error, I don't know why, I just want to create a common table in flink for learning, but he told me that no connector was given, I don't know why, do you have to specify connector when flink builds a table? The following is my statement and error message, please help to read, thank you very much, my flink version is 1.17.2

```sql
CREATE TABLE oa_log_dwd.dwd_operate_log (
  log_id BIGINT, 
  user_id BIGINT, 
  sys_name STRING, 
  module_name STRING, 
  content STRING, 
  business_type INT, 
  `method` STRING, 
  request_method STRING, 
  oper_name STRING, 
  oper_url STRING, 
  oper_ip STRING, 
  status INT, 
  create_time TIMESTAMP, 
  `date` STRING, 
  `year` STRING, 
  `mon` STRING, 
  `day` STRING, 
  `hour` STRING);
```

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Table options do not contain an option key 'connector' for discovering a connector. Therefore, Flink assumes a managed table. However, a managed table factory that implements org.apache.flink.table.factories.ManagedTableFactory is not in the classpath.

Flink SQL> create table tb1 (id int, name string);
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Table options do not contain an option key 'connector' for discovering a connector. Therefore, Flink assumes a managed table. However, a managed table factory that implements org.apache.flink.table.factories.ManagedTableFactory is not in the classpath.
```

I want to know the reason for the error and fix it

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify connector because Flink’s Table API & SQL programs can be connected to other external systems for reading and writing. Depending on the type of source or sink you need a specific connector. For more information you can read [doc page](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/table/overview/#table--sql-connectors).

When you call `CREATE TABLE ...` you need to specify `WITH (...)` part for connector. Read [create-statements](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/table/sql/create/#create-statements) page.

Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee_information (
    emp_id INT,
    name VARCHAR,
    dept_id INT
) WITH ( 
    'connector' = 'filesystem',
    'path' = '/path/to/something.csv',
    'format' = 'csv'
);
```

If you want to try Flink SQL there is DataGen connector. It allows you create tables based on in-memory data generation. [datagen-sql-connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/table/datagen/#datagen-sql-connector)

Comment: One more addition to this: like the error message says, if you don't provide the `WITH` options, Flink assumes you want to create a managed table. A managed table is something that Apache Paimon provides.

Comment: There is a limited number of words in the comments, so I will separate the comments to illustrate my point of view. So do you mean that flinksql must use the with clause to specify a connector? But the scenario I have now is that I have created the mysqlcdc and doris flink tables, respectively, and used mysqlcdc to migrate data from mysql to doris.

Comment: However, there are some calculated fields in the migration process. Suppose I need to split the year month day, and I need to pass part of the field data of the split year month day into table a and another part of the data of the year month day into table b, then I want to directly create an intermediate table inside flink and first split the year month day. Then, based on this intermediate table, the data flow to tables a and b is carried out, so that the calculation process will be reduced by one step. If flink table building must specify the connector, is there another solution for this